# Is a constant such as 8 considered an expression?

Tags: polynomials

The question asked was "Which of the following expressions are considered polynomials?"

8 was one of the answers, and though it is clearly a monomial, it was part of the answer and I'm confused as to how it is an expression.

Answer (score 2):

$8$ is a monomial of degree $0$, which has a constant value: E.g.:
$$8\times x^0\ (\text{Monomial of degree }0)=8$$

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**.

In everyday mathematical usage, an *expression* generally means any syntactic object (i.e. a piece of writing) that denotes some mathematical object, possibly but not necessarily depending one or more variables.